# Example of setting italics in richtextbox with windows forms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

I'm looking for a **complete, working** example of how to set text to italics in a Windows Forms Rich Text Box, **using C++**.

All the examples are similar to the following:

```
System::Drawing::Font comment_font =
    gcnew System::Drawing::Font(m_rich_text_script->SelectionFont,
                System::Drawing::FontStyle::Italic);
m_rich_text_script->SelectionFont = comment_font;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
error C3673: 'System::Drawing::Font' : class does not have a copy-constructor
```

I believe the error is because I'm not including the header file for `System::Drawing::Font`.

I searched the web and stack overflow for "C++ Windows Forms italic" and none of them show the filename to include.  Interestingly, the MSDN sites to not show the #include for C++.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows CLR project on the Win7 platform.

*Background:  I moved the definition of methods from Form1.h to Form1.cpp and #included "Form1.hpp".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a handle to a `System::Drawing::Font` object instead of a stack variable:

```
System::Drawing::Font^ comment_font = ...
```

Below is a complete C++ class that, given a rich text box, sets its selection font to italic:

```
namespace SetToItalic
{
    public ref class SomeClass
    {
    public:
        static void SetRichTextBoxSelectionFontToItalic(
            System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^ textBox)
        {
            System::Drawing::Font^ comment_font =
                gcnew System::Drawing::Font(
                    textBox->SelectionFont,
                    System::Drawing::FontStyle::Italic);

            textBox->SelectionFont = comment_font;
        }
    };
}
```

I have verified this using the toolchain provided with Visual Studio 2013 by having a C# Windows Forms application call into a C++/CLI assembly with the above code.